# How can I upload my project to Github when it is over 100 MB?

Tags: github

I'm using the GoogleMaps pod which is 130MB, so github won't let me upload my project. What is the workaround for this?

[image]

Comment: You can use the Git Large File Storage (see https://github.com/pricing for details). But why do you include the whole SDK in your repository? As far as i understand Pods, it works a bit like Maven, so you don't need the SDK in your repository.

Comment: I just tried that. I installed lfs, then i tracked ".*framework", but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I made a 300MB repository and I'm able to `git add .`, `git commit` and `git push` to a public repo without error. I'm not sure that's the problem.

Comment: @mjb I edited my question by uploading the relevant error message

Comment: @mjb A little late, but I think the maximum single file size is 100mb, not the entire repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest excluding Pods directory (by adding it to your .gitignore file) in your git repository. Pods can be recreated with your podfile, so you don't have to store them in your repository.

Other approach, e.g. when you have framework you precompiled yourself and don't want your other team members to need compile it again, is to use git lfs: https://git-lfs.github.com

Comment: in the .gitignore i typed GoogleMaps.framework and it didn't ignore it. What's up with that?

Comment: @mckamike .gitignore won't affect files that have already been added to your project. (It also won't deal with previous commits that still have a reference to the huge blob -- if it's already been committed, you'll need to jump through some hoops to purge it from your history.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks Yep. I know this isn't a permanent solution...but for those who don't want to jump through those hoops, I just deleted the .git hidden file in my directory and then made the necessary editions to my .gitignore. At that point I was able to successfully put my project onto Github.

Answer (score 1):

If the Google Maps SDK **dependency** is making your project size very large, best to add it to your `.gitignore` rather than keep a copy of the whole thing, whether it be using LFS or whatever other mechanism.

As your project is using Swift, when Xcode supports the Swift Package Manager (SPM), you will be able to specify the Maps SDK as a dependency in your `Package.swift` on a tag or branch basis. And then `swift build` (or the Xcode equivalent) will manage dependency cloning, updates and builds of these type of project dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution you can use a bunch of scripts
like described [in the post here](https://stanfy.com/blog/cocoapods-googlemaps-and-github-restrictions/):

1. Split file

```
   post_install do |installer_representation|
        puts "Splitting up Gooogle Framework - It's just too big to be presented in the Github :("
        Dir.chdir("Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/Current") do
           # Remove previous split files if any
           `rm GoogleMaps_Split_*`
           # Split current framework into smaller parts
           `split -b 30m GoogleMaps GoogleMaps_Split_`
        end
    end
```

2. Add file to .gitignore

```
    # Google Maps is too big to be handled by one file, so this one is generated on build phase from smaller pieces
    OurProject/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/GoogleMaps
```

3. Combine file from chunks on the build step

```
# Github doesn't support files bigger than 100M.
# Latest checked GoogleMaps Framework ~ 114M
# We're expecting to have GoogleMaps Framework as a one file or as a number of chunks

BINARY_FILENAME=GoogleMaps
SPLIT_FILENAME_PREFIX=${BINARY_FILENAME}_Split
GMAPS_FRAMEWORK_DIR=Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/Current
GMAPS_FRAMEWORK_FILE=$GMAPS_FRAMEWORK_DIR/$BINARY_FILENAME

# Check if we  have Google Maps Framework
if [ ! -f ${GMAPS_FRAMEWORK_FILE} ]; then
    echo "There's no Google Maps framework at ${GMAPS_FRAMEWORK_FILE}"
    cd ${GMAPS_FRAMEWORK_DIR}
    #  But we have chunks! ...Probably
    if [ -f ${SPLIT_FILENAME_PREFIX}_aa ]; then
       echo "Creating file from smaller files with ${SPLIT_FILENAME_PREFIX} prefix"
       cat ${SPLIT_FILENAME_PREFIX}_* > ${BINARY_FILENAME}
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Files on GitHub cannot be more than 100MB each with a max total of 1GB unless you're using LFS - https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/

It does not appear to be correct to push the entire directory up to GitHub. Review the documentation or check out examples like this [GoogleDirections binding](https://github.com/poulpix/PXGoogleDirections) that includes a [the necessary json](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/GoogleMaps/1.10.4/GoogleMaps.podspec.json).

Answer (score 0):

Per Github's disk [quota page](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/), there is only a strict limit of 100MB on **individual files**. There is a recommended 1GB repository limit as well.

If you are working with a very large file, I recommend reading this page [here](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/), which will detail what you should do. Notably, they recommend Git Large File Storage if you absolutely need to push a large file.

> Tip: If you regularly push large files to GitHub, consider introducing Git Large File Storage (Git LFS) as part of your workflow. Git LFS works well with the [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) and can be used with any large file, regardless of its type. For more information, see "[Versioning large files](https://help.github.com/articles/versioning-large-files/)."

However, in this case it really looks like you should be either creating a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or flat out using .gitignore to remove the framework from the repository.

Comment: I used that to track "*.framework" but that didn't work. I then added GoogleMaps.Framework to the .gitignore but to no avail. It seems like that framework isn't being ignored.