# Trying to upload AudioKit Framework into GitHub

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am working on a project to detect audio input and analyze the frequency and amplitude.

I was trying to use similar code like Microphone analysis.

While working on it, I had to use the latest version of the AudioKit framework and in order to do so I had to upload the AudioKit.framework and AudioKitUI.framework files to my project.

After uploading, I try to commit and push the project to Github but Since the AudioKit file was over 152 MB. It would not allow me up push the project to github account.

Is there any way around it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload my project to Github when it is over 100 MB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520723/how-can-i-upload-my-project-to-github-when-it-is-over-100-mb)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Cocoapods with our staging server.  That is basically a Cocoapod based on the staging branch of AudioKit, which is close to the develop branch.

Use a podfile like this one: https://github.com/AudioKit/AnalogSynthX/blob/master/Podfile

```
# Comment the following line to switch to the mainstream AudioKit pod
source 'https://github.com/AudioKit/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

Basically this tells Cocoapods to look at our specs first.  Then the line:

```
pod 'AudioKit'
```

gets the most recent version.